# Catalan's conjecture simplified

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

I am trying to undestand an easier version of Catalan's conjecture. Instead of $a^x-b^y=1$ we try prove that if $x=2$ then that only possible nontrivial solution for this equation is $a=3, b=2, y=3$.

The solution is described in https://vixra.org/pdf/1906.0374v1.pdf
. But I struggle to understand why $p^y-q^y=2$ implies $p-q$ divides $2$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is not an easier version, it is a special case.

Comment: yeah, I also think it is easier since the proof does not contain number theory

Comment: $p^y-q^y=(p-q)\times \sum_{i=1}^n p^{y-i}q^{i-1}$.